# Windows Explorer/Control Panel not opening

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I have windows 10 installed, this problem started this morning, it was working fine before. After I turned on my Laptop (Hp Pavilion), I'm not able to open any folder, I'm getting a blank screen for 2 seconds than the desktop refreshes.
Plus i cant open my Cd Tray anymore...

Any idea if its a virus?

I tried the "change the icon size and font size" fix and its not working

Note: if i open a folder using cmd, it opens but even after that when i try to modify a file or enter another nested folder, it crashes and im back to the desktop screen again.

Comment: Sounds like explorer.exe is crashing whenever you try to open something. "Any ideas if its a virus?" Being it could be just about anything, no, I have no idea. What have you done to try to solve the issue?

Comment: Did you try another restart?

Comment: Agree 100% with Moab.... Windows just had updated released so simply restart and check again just in case. Easy peasy if that's the solution.

Comment: I did like 10 restarts since then, I installed the new updates and still the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log on other user account to see if it can open folder/ Windows Explorer/Control Panel.

Try to boot into safe mode to see if it can work. Start your PC in safe mode in Windows 10:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode

Check if the PC is up to date.

Comment: Working fine on the new user. so the only option here is to switch to a new user? theres no fix?

Comment: It may cause by corrupted user profile, here are links may help you fix it.
Corrupt User Profile: Fix for Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, 10:
https://neosmart.net/wiki/corrupt-user-profile/
Repair user profile:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bc079578-2b9f-44a9-b225-e4df74abdc4c/repair-user-profile?forum=win10itprogeneral